# async/await not act in dynamodb in aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, async-await, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use async await at dynamodb in aws lambda but it doesn't act.
My code is as below.

```
async function(){
        var params1 = {
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":id": {S:id.toString()}
            },
            KeyConditionExpression: "id = :id",
            ProjectionExpression: 'id, email',
            TableName: 'users',
            IndexName: 'id-index',
        };
        
        const basedata = async () =>{
            try {
                const data = await ddb.query(params1).promise()
                console.log("Success")
                console.log(data)
                return data
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Failure", err.message)
                // there is no data here, you can return undefined or similar
            }
        } 
        let data = await basedata()
        callback(null, data)
     }
```

When I didn't use the async await then the callback acts well and response exact data, but when I use async await it doesn't act.i.e response null. Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return instead of callback

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

Comment: I did as you said. But the action is the same. I replace callback with return and it also returns null. And there is no logs for console.log at first and after some time, I execute the lambda function again then there happens logs for the first time.